# Returning customer information from Paypal Client Side REST Integration Button

Tags: rest, paypal, paypal-rest-sdk, paypal-buttons

I am using the "Client Side REST Integration" using checkout.js (https://developer.paypal.com/docs/integration/direct/express-checkout/integration-jsv4/client-side-REST-integration/)

Is there a way to return the client's information (name + email address) once authorized and the paypal window closes?

Somewhere in the following perhaps?

```
onAuthorize: function(data, actions) {

    // Make a call to the REST api to execute the payment
    return actions.payment.execute().then(function() {
    window.alert('Payment Complete!');
 });
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Answered for myself:
actions.payment.execute().then() returns a payment object with this info

```
onAuthorize: function(data, actions) {

    return actions.payment.execute().then(function(payment) {
        console.log(payment.payer.payer_info);
    });
}
```